# CORS AngularJS/NestJS

Tags: angular, cors, nestjs

Trying to login but it gives me this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/api/auth/login' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Register works perfectly.

### `main.ts` of NestJS

```
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { cors: true });
  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({ whitelist: true, forbidNonWhitelisted: true }),
    );

    app.use((req, res, next) => {
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept');
      next();
  });

  app.enableCors({
      allowedHeaders:"*",
      origin: "*"
  });
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

### `login.component.ts`

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  form!: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: '',
      password: ''
    });
  }

  submit(): void {
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/auth/login', this.form.getRawValue(), {
      withCredentials: true
    }).subscribe(() => this.router.navigate(['/']));
  }
}
```

Comment: The error message is *very* clear. `withCredentials: true` and a wildcard (*) origin is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty plainly said

> The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.

You need to set the origin as a specific value. Any reason to not use `app.enableCors()` instead of a custom middleware? Otherwise, just set

```js
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');
```

Comment: You're missing the `http://` bit.